# JavaFx program is not responding?

Tags: java

when i run this code java not responding with java Result: -805306369 .

this code try to unrar a rar file with junrar.
what is java Result: -805306369 ?

is this error for low memory?

how can i solve it?

thanks.

```
 String filename = importFile.getAbsolutePath();
    File f = new File(filename);
    Archive a = null;
    try {
        a = new Archive(f);
    } catch (RarException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (a != null) {
        FileHeader fh = a.nextFileHeader();
        while (fh != null) {
        try {
                        if(fh.getFileNameString().endsWith(".jml")){
                                    Path tempJml=Files.createTempFile("jml",".jml");
                                    FileOutputStream outJml=new FileOutputStream(tempJml.toFile());                       
                                    InputStream in=a.getInputStream(fh);                       
                                     int lenj;
                                      while ((lenj = in.read(buffer))>0 ) {
                                      outJml.write(buffer, 0, lenj);
                                       }
                                    outJml.close();
                                     in.close();
                                  ZipFile zpjml=new ZipFile(tempJml.toFile());
                                   zpjml.stream().forEach((jmlEntry)->{ 
                                   System.out.println(jmlEntry.getName());
                                   if(jmlEntry.getName().endsWith(".xml")){
                                try {
                                    InputStream x = null;
                                    try {
                                        x = zpjml.getInputStream(jmlEntry);
                                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                                        Logger.getLogger(ConvertController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                    }
                                    List<Card> xml = convertXml(x);
                                    if(xml!=null){
                                         xmlPat = createNewXml(xml,jmlEntry.getName());
                                    }
                                    ZipEntry newZe=new ZipEntry(jmlEntry.getName().substring(0,jmlEntry.getName().lastIndexOf("."))+".xml");
                                    zos.putNextEntry(newZe);
                                    InputStream inXml=new FileInputStream(xmlPat);

                                    int len;
                                    while ((len = inXml.read(buffer))>0 ) {
                                        zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                                    }
                                    zos.closeEntry();
                                    inXml.close();
                                    x.close();
                                    Path temp=Paths.get(xmlPat);
                                    Files.deleteIfExists(temp);
                                } catch (DocumentException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(ConvertController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                } catch (IOException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(ConvertController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }
                             }else if(jmlEntry.getName().startsWith("images")){
                                 try (InputStream inImag = zpjml.getInputStream(jmlEntry)) {
                                     ZipEntry newZe=new ZipEntry(jmlEntry.getName());
                                zos.putNextEntry(newZe);
                                   int len;
                                   while ((len = inImag.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                       zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                                   }

                                   zos.closeEntry();
                                   inImag.close();
                               } catch (IOException ex) {          
                                    Logger.getLogger(ConvertController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }          
                             }

                        });


                        }
                    else if(fh.getFileNameString().endsWith(".xml")){
                                    InputStream in=a.getInputStream(fh);
                                    List<Card> xml = convertXml(in);
                                    if(xml!=null){
                                     xmlPath = createNewXml(xml,fh.getFileNameString());
                                    }
                                    ZipEntry newZe=new ZipEntry(fh.getFileNameString().substring(0,fh.getFileNameString().lastIndexOf("."))+".xml");            
                                    zos.putNextEntry(newZe);
                                    InputStream inXml = new FileInputStream(xmlPath);
                                       int len;
                                       while ((len = inXml.read(buffer))>0 ) {
                                           zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                                       }
                                       in.close();
                                       zos.closeEntry();
                                       inXml.close();
                                    }
                    else if(fh.getFileNameString().startsWith("images")){
                                     ZipEntry newZe=new ZipEntry(fh.getFileNameString());
                                     zos.putNextEntry(newZe);
                                       InputStream inFile=a.getInputStream(fh);
                                        int len;
                                          while ((len = inFile.read(buffer))>0 ) {
                                            zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                                        }

                                        inFile.close();
                                        zos.closeEntry();

                                }else{
                        continue;
                    }
                            }catch(RarException | IOException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
            fh = a.nextFileHeader();
        }

    }

             zos.close();
```

Comment: Please post the question properly

Comment: please format all your code

Comment: I solve this problem ,i remove try-catch and last else in my code.